# How do I change fonts on all of my pages in my style sheet?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm building a basic website and I've gotten pretty far, but I have stumbled upon a problem: I want all of my headings to be in the font "Arvo", but for some reason, only the index page has Arvo in the heading. Since all of my pages are linked to the stylesheet I should be able to change every h1 to this font.

Here's what my style sheet looks like, there's probably some unnecessary code in there, but I'm a total beginner.

```
body {
  background: url("https://www.xmple.com/wallpaper/streaks-lines-red-stripes-1920x1080-c4-7f2a33-972c36-b02c39-cb2b3b-l4-45-72-116-187-a-135-f-1.svg") center center repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#wrap {
  width: 54%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff2f9;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 15px;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 100px 100px #ffffff, 0 10px 15px #000;
}

p {
  color: black;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Arvo', Georgia, Times, serif; 
  font-size: 59px;
  line-height: 70px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

b {
  font-family: "verdana", sans-serif; color: gold;
  text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 1px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;
}

a {
  font-family: "verdana", sans-serif; 
  color: black /* unvisited link */
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
  color: black;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
  color: gold;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
  color: black;
}

}
```

What else do I need to do for the font to change on all of my HTML pages?

Comment: You should ensure that all of your other pages reference the same style sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the style is override, therefore use `!important` to fix it.
Use the following CSS for all headings:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-family: Arvo, Georgia, Times, serif !important; 
font-size: 59px;
line-height: 70px;
}
```

If you want to apply it only for `h1` then remove the rest of headings. In the question you said "all headings", therefore, I added the all heading levels.

**Update:**
Try linking the font with your page, put the following inside `head` element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" />
```

**Or**
Import the font. Put the following line in the very begining of your CSS:

```
@import url('href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo');
```

Comment: That didn't seem to make a difference, unfortunately.

Comment: @KnugenavSwärje Is the document online to check?

Comment: You mean if it's on a domain? In that case, no.

Comment: @KnugenavSwärje Try using inspect element on the page where style is not applying, and see what `font-family` is applied to `h1`.

Comment: @KnugenavSwärje yeah, It is applied, and also see the updated answer.

Comment: @KnugenavSwärje It might be that `Arvo` font is missing. You have to import or link with it. see the answer again.